# NIKTO: Requires Authentication for realm ''MD5''

Tags: http, webserver, vulnerability-scanners

I am trying to perform a scanning of a web server using Nikto using:

```
nikto -id id:pass -h xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

I am specifying HTTP Basic authentication credentials and indeed with this credentials I can log to the IP address I am scanning. So I am expecting result, but instead I am getting the following:

```
 Server: blahblah
+ The anti-clickjacking X-Frame-Options header is not present.
+ The X-XSS-Protection header is not defined. This header can hint to the 
user agent to protect against some forms of XSS
+ The X-Content-Type-Options header is not set. This could allow the user 
agent to render the content of the site in a different fashion to the MIME type
+ / - Requires Authentication for realm 'MD5'
+ No CGI Directories found (use '-C all' to force check all possible dirs)
+ / - Requires Authentication for realm 'MD5'
+ / - Requires Authentication for realm 'MD5'
```

I assumed the problem is with the HTTP credentials, but I am adding the right one. Since Nikto is new to me I cannot really understand what the issue is.

Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

As Nikto's [README.md](https://github.com/sullo/nikto/blob/40867b08f5a9c5c8897da92c1d23ff3d1a446b4c/README.md) point out; The parameter for host authentication `-id`'s format is:

- `id:pass` **or** `id:pass:realm`

You can probably try this: `nikto -id id:pass:MD5 -h xxx.xxx.xx.xxx`

Also, you can find [here](https://github.com/sullo/nikto/blob/40867b08f5a9c5c8897da92c1d23ff3d1a446b4c/program/plugins/nikto_auth.plugin) the authentication plugin's code (*written in Perl*), and [here](https://github.com/sullo/nikto/wiki) the Wiki of this project.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the possible reason for this authentication message? I do not get it anytime, but when I am testing a specific dns.

Comment: Unfortunately, Nikto's documentation doesn't provide any insight about this specific message. But, based on plugin's code ([link](https://github.com/sullo/nikto/blob/40867b08f5a9c5c8897da92c1d23ff3d1a446b4c/program/plugins/nikto_auth.plugin#L125)), it tries to read the authentication header of host and if it finds a specific realm (like MD5), outputs this message to inform you. Did `id:pass:realm` worked in this case?